# Check procedure SSL & CA Certificate by using browser

Tags: ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate, cache

The SSL certification limit is comming
so I'd like to upgrade these certifications.

Is there any solutions that check the certifications withought server proxy's cache?
We have to been under proxy environment.

How can I clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to confirm it's valid from the website:

```
openssl s_client -connect <my url>:443
```

Or otherwise to verify the certificate chains on the file system before putting them on the website.

```
openssl verify [-CApath directory] cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are not too reliable a testing tool for ssl certificate verification any longer because browser writers have been bundling a lot of certificates into the browser's keystore--certificates that one doesn't necessarily expect to see there.  cUrl and openssl still seem to be the most reliable tools for verification for me.  Also, some Certificate Authorities provide their own verification tools but you're limited in that the site you're looking to check must be Internet accessible.